# DataTables - File Location

Tags: datatables

http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

I am running an older version of DataTables, which so far has proven satisfactory for my needs. I have found the answer I am seeking, but just don't know WHERE?? the file is located within DataTables folder structure ???? - ( I want to make changes to the default # of records shown )

aLengthMenu

```
 `[!$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#example').dataTable( {
 "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
 } );
 } );


// Setting the default display length as well as length menu
// This is likely to be wanted if you remove the '10' option which
// is the iDisplayLength default.
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"iDisplayLength": 25,
"aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]]
} );
} );`
```

Any suggestions as to where this piece of code is located so I can change it?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: there is a standard answer for this if you are still in need

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't. 
If you change the source code for a plugin, you lock yourself into either changing the source code every time the plugin gets updated or forcing yourself to use an outdated library/plugin.

Like most jquery plugins, you can change the defaults when the page loads before the pluging is used.  I actually put all my defaults in a single file that I load after the other files load.

```
<script src='pathtojquery.js'></script>
<script src='pathtojqueryUI.js></script>
<script src='pathtoDatatables.js></script>
<script src='pathtoMyDefaults.js></script>
```

in pathtoMyDefaults.js, I have this line, among others:

```
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.aLengthMenu = [[5, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 75, -1], [5, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 75, "All"]];
```

You can examine $.fn.dataTable.defaults with a javascript debugger to see all of the defaults.

then in my code I just have to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#tblSelector").DataTable({stuff:"stuff",
        // if page length is not included, or does not match what is in the array, it defaults to the last one in the array.
           pageLength: 8,
           moreStuff:"moreStuff"
       } )
});
```

Comment: this was tested in version 1.10 but since this is a standard practice, it should hold true for earlier versions.